# How can i create a custom listview in SherlocklistActivity?

Tags: java, android, listview, mobile

I have not worked on sherlock i wanna create a sherclockactionbar interface with two to three tabs at one tab i wanna have a listview with a sub item text it works on simple activity but it is not working in sherlockfragmentactivity.And i wanna disable title bar i have successfully disable it on android 3.0 and greater but it is still showing on android version less than 3.0.

```
public class FragmentListArraySupport extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        ArrayListFragment list = new ArrayListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
    }
}

public static class ArrayListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
  public static final String[] items = ("first","second","third");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why not to use a normal `SherlockFragment` then set the content of it with your `CustomListView`?

Comment: can you please provide a little code for help?